# How can I disable UNITCHECK blocks conditionally?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, package

I wrote some Perl packages using `UNITCHECK` (mostly to make sure that some change doesn't break it).
As some checks are "heavy" (e.g. creating a temporary database, or waiting for time to elapse), there are situations when I don't want the checks to be performed (e.g. when using such a package.

I wonder: Is there a way to *conditionally disable* execution of a `UNITCHECK` block in a way that *does not* require a change to the package source?

I could think of something like

```perl
our $DISABLE_UNITCHECK = 0;
#...
UNITCHECK {
    unless ($DISABLE_UNITCHECK) {
        # all the UNITCHECK code goes here
    }
}
```

But how to set the variable in a clever way?
What makes it tricky also is the fact that the `UNITCHECK` is only run once when the package is loaded for the first time, right?

Comment: No. Probably should have used something like `return if !$ENV{TESTING};`

Comment: But that's not very selective regarding multiple packages then.

Comment: That's the point. You already have a package-specific way, but you asked for a universal one. And it can be as selective as you want to, say by making the value a list of package names instead of a boolean. The point is to use something external, such as an env var.

Comment: Well, you would have a package specific way is you removed the `= 0`. You'd probably want the reverse the logic too (`$ENABLE_UNITCHECK`).

Comment: Is there something that makes `UNITCHECK` better than simple tests to check if some change didn't break it? Just curious.

Comment: @briandfoy Plead define *simple tests*: Some commands being entered interactively, or some existing functions being called? Maybe give an example.

Comment: I'm not trying to be glib, but simple tests are those that aren't complex. That is, you don't have to force the code to do things that are unusual or unwieldy. I can't really say more because this is all relative to the task.

Answer (score 1):

After having read the comments I came up with this solution:
The package will *not* use the `UNITCHECK` by default, but will use it if importing the "magic" `UNITCHECK` symbol (i.e.: `use Package qw(UNITCHECK)`).
However you cannot enable the `UNITCHECK` while importing nothing (i.e.: `use Package qw(UNITCHECK)` will import the defaut set).

Here's the code fragment:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

package Package;

our (@EXPORT, @ISA, $VERSION);

BEGIN {
    use Exporter;
    $VERSION = 'v0.0.0';                # for version checking
    @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    #@EXPORT = ...
}

our $UNITCHECK = 0;

sub import
{
    @_ = grep { if ($_ eq 'UNITCHECK') { $UNITCHECK = 1; 0 } else { 1 }  } @_;
    # Exporter::import will export to the caller's namespace
    # (that would be __PACKAGE__).  Using goto makes Exporter::import use
    # the caller of this import routine instead.  Also pass original @_.
    goto &Exporter::import;
}

UNITCHECK {
    if ($UNITCHECK) {
        print "checking unit\n";
    }
}

1;
```

Of course, to strictly answer the question, one would use the symbol `NO_UNITCHECK`, default `$UNITCHECK = 1`, and eventually use the inverted logic in `grep`...

One could even extend the code to cause the magic `(NO_)?UNITCHECK` token to apply to modules used in a recursive way.